# Reading a Facebook feed in C#

Tags: c#, xml, facebook

I want to read an XML stream from a Facebook page. When I try to run the following code, I get the error "An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 10, position 53.". Why and how do I solve it?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var feed = RssManager.ReadFeed("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=145493382141206&format=rss20");
        foreach (var item in feed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("***********************************************");
            Console.WriteLine("Title:" + item.title);
            Console.WriteLine("Link:" + item.link);
            Console.WriteLine("Description:" + item.description);
            Console.WriteLine("Language:" + item.language);
            Console.WriteLine("Publish Date:" + item.pubdate);
            Console.WriteLine("***********************************************");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class RssFeedItem
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string pubdate { get; set; }
}

public static class RssManager
{
    public static List<RssFeedItem> ReadFeed(string url)
    {
        List<RssFeedItem> rssItems = new List<RssFeedItem>();
        HttpWebRequest rssFeed = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        using (DataSet rssData = new DataSet())
        {
            var response = rssFeed.GetResponse();
            var data = response.GetResponseStream();
            rssData.ReadXml(data);
            foreach (DataRow datarow in rssData.Tables["item"].Rows)
            {
                rssItems.Add(new RssFeedItem
                {
                    description = Convert.ToString(datarow["description"]),
                    language = Convert.ToString(datarow["language"]),
                    link = Convert.ToString(datarow["link"]),
                    pubdate = Convert.ToString(datarow["pubdate"]),
                    title = Convert.ToString(datarow["title"])
                });
            }
        }
        return rssItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a Dataset to parse an RSS is not a very good approach (not every XML schema can be interpreted as a Dataset). I would try using something else: see [this answer using XDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002989/load-xml-file-from-website-into-xdocument-silverlight-and-wp7) for instance

Comment: When I try using XDocument i get the same error.

"An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 10, position 53."

Comment: @RonSplinter Have you looked at the returned string? Is it possible that it is an html page?

Comment: No, its xml. You can see the file at https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=145493382141206&format=rss20

Comment: Yes, it returns xml in browsers but an html page when using `WebClient.DownloadString` (complaining about unsupported browser)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code snippet below returns an error page about unsupported browsers.

```
HttpWebRequest rssFeed = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=145493382141206&format=rss20");
Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(rssFeed.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
```

It will work fine if you add this line:

```
rssFeed.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)";
```

--- EDIT---

The above solution will enable you to pass XML exceptions thrown at  `rssData.ReadXml(data)`. But your code still have problems with parsing RSS (I commented out `language = Convert.ToString(datarow["language"])`).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "pubDate" instead of "pubdate"?